# Generate Parenthesis - where am I going wrong

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

So here's the problem. For a given `n` we need to generate all valid parenthesis.

For e.g, for `n=2` the possible output will be `()()`, `(()))`

So I tried solving using recursion and backtracking.

I take two variables, open_bracket and close_bracket along with a ds to store the parenthesis.

Here's my recursive diagram looks like

[image: Here's my recursive diagram looks like]

So with that I tried this:

```js
function generatePArenthesis(n, open_bracket=0, close_bracket=0, ds=[]){
    if(open_bracket === n && close_bracket === n){
    console.log(ds.toString());
    return
  }
  
  if(open_bracket < n){
    ds.push('(');
    generatePArenthesis(n, open_bracket+ 1, close_bracket, ds);
  }
  
  if(close_bracket<open_bracket){
    ds.push(')');
    generatePArenthesis(n, open_bracket, close_bracket +1, ds);
  }
  
}

generatePArenthesis(2)
```

when I dry run this program for `n=2` it does seem to produce the above recursive diagram. But doesn't give me the correct output. Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restore `ds` after recursive calls:

```js
function generatePArenthesis(n, open_bracket=0, close_bracket=0, ds=[]){
    if(open_bracket === n && close_bracket === n){
    console.log(ds.toString());
    return
  }
  
  if(open_bracket < n){
    ds.push('(');
    generatePArenthesis(n, open_bracket+ 1, close_bracket, ds);
    ds.pop();
  }
  
  if(close_bracket<open_bracket){
    ds.push(')');
    generatePArenthesis(n, open_bracket, close_bracket +1, ds);
        ds.pop();
  }
  
}

generatePArenthesis(3)
```

Comment: can you please explain why as in my recursive tree, I'm pushing into the existing content without clearing it and it still produces the output correctly.

Comment: When you first made `(,(,),)` in left big branch, `ds` contains 4 items and it is used in the right branch, so you add `(` not to `(,)` as you wanted but to `(,(,),)`

Comment: You are using single instance of `ds` everywhere. You can create new copies in recursive calls (I don't know JS enough, but something like `generatePArenthesis(n, open_bracket+ 1, close_bracket, ds +'(')`

Comment: That’s right. Like this `[…ds, ‘(‘]`